# Fail to build openjdk 7 update 6

Tags: java, openjdk

I downloaded the archive of openjdk 7 update 6 from this page:

https://jdk7.java.net/source.html

I tried to build it by following the README-builds.html but failed with lots of errors like "unmappable character for encoding ascii". For example:

../../../src/share/classes/javax/transaction/._TransactionRequiredException.java:1: error: unmappable character for encoding ascii.

I tried on both mac 10.7.5 and debian 6, but both failed with the same errors.

This file "corbar/src/share/classes/javax/transaction/.*TransactionRequiredException.java" looks like binary file and I am not sure why it has the prefix ".*". Anybody had this issue before? How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure Stack Overflow is the best place for this question, as it does not relate specifically to programming or algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the build is failing because the character encoding of the Java code you downloaded contains non-ASCII characters ... and you have ASCII as the default characterset for your system(s):

Examine the file(s) in question to try to identify the non-ASCII characters, then:

- change your default characterset to UTF-8 (or whatever) to match the file encoding, OR
- convert the offending files to ASCII using the `native2ascii` tool that comes as part of a standard JDK distribution.

---

> This file "corbar/src/share/classes/javax/transaction/.TransactionRequiredException.java" looks like binary file and I am not sure why it has the prefix ".". Anybody had this issue before? How can I fix it?

Did you try renaming it to get rid of the leading "."?